# Add a menu to a GtkMenuToolButton (Python)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

In my Python application I have some GtkMenuItems (associated with the main GtkMenuBar), and some GtkMenuToolButtons inside my GtkToolbar.

```
- gtkMenuBar1
   - gtkMenuItem1
      - gtkMenuItem2
      - gtkMenuItem3
- gtkToolbar1
   - gtkMenuToolButton1
```

By default, gtkMenuToolButton1 is obviously empty. I want to do something like

```
self.ui.gtkMenuToolButton1.set_menu(self.ui.gtkMenuItem1)
```

But if I do that (inside `finish_initializing()` of my window), nothing changes. I'm new to Python and Gtk3. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `Gtk.Menu` object to the menu tool button, not a `Gtk.MenuItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the examples in [Python Gtk3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/menus.html#example)

Comment: Thank you! That's a useful website